# Could I use Ubuntu/Linux keyboard layout in Mac OS X with a PC keyboard?

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard-layout

I'm a used Ubuntu user on a pc, and I like the french keyboard layout because it allows me to type accentued characters easily.

I found a win-fr keyboard layout but it's much like windows and not so good.

I found xmodmap.fr keyboard layout and I'd like to know if it was possible use it with my Mac SL 10.6.5, maybe I could do xmodmap xmodmap.fr or a way to convert to mac layout file.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System Preferences (`/Applications/System Preferences`) and then click on "Language and Text" and go to the "Input Sources" tab, you can select the "French" layout. You can then uncheck the "English" layout if you would like. Your keyboard should be using a French keyboard layout.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I know this, that's just I'm using a windows keyboard, so keys are placed differently, for example the < and > are difficult to access and I'm programming a lot.. So I'd like to replace this. I'd also like to have the same layout I had on Ubuntu